# Keycloak- SpringBoot Adapter how to expose actuator endpoint with policy

Tags: java, spring-boot, authorization, keycloak

I am using spring boot 2.6.2、actuator and keycloak 16.1.0.
the pom of springboot is

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>16.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
      <version>16.1.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

the application.properties for keycloak config is

```
keycloak.realm=mt-developer
keycloak.resource=test
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://local.host:8080/auth/
keycloak.credentials.secret=ZMRQ0OPiXZFONCpdNO0G7zLnq5IDIcvM
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=false
keycloak.bearer-only=false
keycloak.autodetect-bearer-only=true
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=all
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/actuator
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[1]=/actuator/*
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.cors=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

this config can expose /actuator and /actuator/* , then i want to control the authorization on keycloak platform, so i add

```
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.lazy-load-paths=true
```

into the properties to active the policy-enforcer, then i can config the authorization on the platform ,but this config will make the config of security-constraints not work .when i request the /actuator path , it will return 403 code .
Can i expose the path by config the setting of the platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use keycloak adapters for spring, [it is deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

Read [this tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for alternatives.

Second, why using policies which are far less efficient than role based access control with JWT access-tokens?

Just declare a "confidential" client in keycloak with a role named something like `SYTEM_MONITOR` or whatever you like and configure spring-security with `http.authorizeExchange()    .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("SYTEM_MONITOR")`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer，this is a great inspiration for me. I really should consider not using deprecated adapter anymore. I tried spring security and find that i should deal with JWT token myself and i still don't know how to get the RBAC configuration from keycloak server to the spring security configuration. Now the RBAC control is made by the application file of the springboot service ,if some role need change the access path , i need to change the application file, Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Roles are not part of OpenID nor OAuth2. It is always implemented as private claims and each vendor chooses its claims. In the tutorials linked in the answer, you'll find configuration for Keyckloak. Good news is: if you switch to another OpenID vendor than Keycloak, all you have to change is a line in application-properties (or a command line argument).